Issue with Custom Bucket Structure Rule - Lost Child Items in Content Tree
I have created a custom bucket structure rule to reorganize our news articles.
Current folder structure configuration:

The rule is designed to create folders based on year and month.
While the rule functions correctly for creating the desired folder structure,
I am experiencing an issue where child items are being lost from the content tree. As you see in below image we lost our ContentBlock item.
After adding rule the folder structure configuration:

I would appreciate guidance on any additional configurations or settings that might help preserve
child items during this restructuring process.
Thank you in advance for your assistance.

For this you are using existing bucket rules or you have crated your own custom rule?

i have created my own custom rule.

As I can see and you are saying your rule are working fine. But you lost your Child Items in Content Tree.
So in order to fix this issue you may need to do some configuration on your template level.
In Templates standard values you can see there is one section Item Buckets here you may need to maintain child relationship.
As shown in below image please add these configurations on Templates standard values and check again.

May this configuration will help you. Please Let me know in case you face any issues.

Thanks, that was worked for me

You will need to enable the lock child relationship on the news item template standard value in order to make sure the child items are visible.

Once above changes are done, you should be able to see content items created beneath the news item. You can find more details here.
Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you face any issues.
